# Does $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ have elements of order $4$ and $12$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ has an element of order $4$. But does it also has an element of order $12$?

Comment: There are only 24 elements in this group. You can write them down and compute their orders. That will answer your question, and be good practice. When you think there's a "theoretical" way to solve a problem but can't quite see it, compute some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $S_3$ has an element of order $3$ and $3$ is coprime to $4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Suppose we have a direct product of groups $G_1 \times G_2$ and elements $g_1 \in G_1$ and $g_2 \in G_2$ of finite order.  You can prove that the order of $(g_1, g_2) \in G_1 \times G_2$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(g_1, g_2)$.

Another helpful fact to prove:  $\displaystyle \operatorname{lcm}(a, b) = \frac{ab}{\gcd(a, b)}$